# show animation in one JLayeredPane then show another JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, animation

I have a problem, I programming a game.
in game there are two JLayeredPanes. One is pazarEkrani. Other is haritaEkrani.
in haritaEkrani JLayeredPane, there is a animation.
From pazarEkrani JLayeredPane, I click a button then, I want to display animation in haritaEkrani JLayerdPane. After animation finished, I want to active pazarEkrani JLayeredPane again.

For below code, Animation is work.
When I comment out last two line in below code animation didn't work and pazarEkrani JLayeredPane is displayed.
What should I do? Thanks...

```
    pazarEkrani.setVisible(false);
    haritaEkrani = new Animation();

   //JLabel image for background
    haritaEkraniBGIJL = new JLabel();
    haritaEkraniBGIJL.setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/images/ipekYolu1.jpg"));
    haritaEkraniBGIJL.setSize(800, 600);
    haritaEkraniBGIJL.setLocation(0, 0);
    haritaEkrani.add( haritaEkraniBGIJL,new Integer(1) );


    pencere.add(haritaEkrani,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //pencere.remove(haritaEkrani);
    //pazarEkrani.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a layered pane. Instead use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Then when the animation stops you just swap the panel that you want to see.

Comment: I have to use JlayeredPane. there are components in LayeredPane.

Comment: Componets must be on each others.

Comment: @birolt, Then use something like the [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/). the panel contains an image and you can also add components to the panel.

Comment: First, I want display animation JlayeredPane then automatic pass the another JlayeredPane.

Comment: Your requirement still doesn't make sense to me. Just because you are currently using layered pane doesn't mean that should be your final solution. I have given you two different solutions. You have been asked for a `SSCCE`. Without one I will not be able to understand your verbal description of the requirement.